# How to dynamically set environment variables of linked containers?

Tags: docker

I have two containers `webinterface` and `db`, while `webinterface` is started using the `--link` option (for `db`) which generates the environment variables

```
DB_PORT_1111_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.5:5432
DB_PORT_1111_TCP_PROTO=tcp
DB_PORT_1111_TCP_PORT=1111
DB_PORT_1111_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.5
...
```

Now my `webinterface` container uses a `Dockerfile` where some static environment variables are defined to define the connection:

```
ENV DB_HOST localhost
ENV DB_PORT 2222
```

Knowing that there is also an `-e` option for `docker run`, the problem is that I want to use those variables in the `Dockerfile` (used in some scripts) but overwrite them with the values generated with the `--link` option, i.e. something like:

```
docker run -d -e DB_HOST=$DB_PORT_1111_TCP_ADDR
```

This would use the host's defined environment variable which doesn't work here.
Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: when you use the --link flag docker updates /etc/hosts - can you just reference DB_HOST by the host name?

Comment: what happens when you try docker run -d -e DB_HOST="$DB_PORT"_1111_TCP_ADDR

Comment: @jimmy: this is for the hostname only

Comment: @booyaa: this resolves to an empty string at runtime: DB_PORT = ""

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: unfortunately not :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable expansion issue so to resolve try the following:

`docker run -d -e DB_HOST="$DB_PORT"_1111_TCP_ADDR`

Answer (score 0):

With a Unix process that is already running, its environment variables can only be changed from inside the process, not from the outside, so their are somewhat non-dynamic by nature.

If you find Docker links limiting, you are not the only person out there. One simple solution to this would be using [WeaveDNS](https://github.com/zettio/weave/tree/master/weavedns#readme). With WeaveDNS you can simply use default ports (as with Weave overlay network there is no need to expose/publish/remap any internal ports) and resolve each component by via DNS (i.e. your app would just need to look for `db.weave.local`, and doesn't need to be aware of clunky environment variable scheme that Docker links present). To get a better idea of how WeaveDNS works, checkout [one of the official getting started guides](http://weave.works/guides/weave-docker-nginx-ubuntu-simple.html). WeaveDNS effectively gives you service discovery without having to modify the application you have.

Comment: _Disclaimer: I am from Weave team._